# Iniciar sesion con procedimiento almacenado con laravel

Tags: laravel, laragon

Que tal amigos acudo a ustedes genios de la programación, tengo un problema, resulta ser que tengo que hacer un login con laravel eso no es problema para mí, lo que, si es que ya hay una base de datos y procedimientos almacenados, ahora he intentado hacer login y efectivamente me deja pasar a las rutas protegidas, pero mi pregunta es realmente es seguro hacerlo de esta manera o utilizo un procedimiento que ya existe, ejecute en otra ruta el procedimiento almacenado del login que tienen y lo probé con un formulario y efectivamente funciona me devuelve solo 0 si es incorrecto los datos y me devuelve 1 si son correctos, pero el detalle es lo del cerrar sesión, qué recomendación sugieren, ya que estoy tomando muy en cuenta lo del token csrf y que las rutas queden protegidas, les dejo el código de mis rutas en próximo cambiare el código al controlador ;)

```
Route::post('login', function (Request $request){

$idUsuario = $request->input('user');
$contrasena = $request->input('Contraseña');

        $user = User::where('Id_Usuario', $idUsuario)->first();
       // return $user->only('Contrasena');



        if ($user && $user->Contrasena === $contrasena) {
            // Autenticar al usuario manualmente
           \Auth::login($user);
           request()->session()->regenerate();
           // return "holaaaa";
           return redirect('menu');

        } else {
            return "error al logear";
        }
   
})->name('login.val');

Route::view('menu','menu')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('logout',[UsuarioController::class,'logout'])->name('cerrar.usuario');
```